# Is this proposition true? (a limit of a sum of multivariable functions equals to the sum of limits of the functions)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that:
$$
\biggl(\lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} f(x, y) = K \biggl) 
\land
\biggl( \lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} g(x, y) = L \biggl)
\Rightarrow
\biggl(\lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} (f+g)(x, y) = K + L \biggl)
$$

And I can prove it using $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition. But I couldn't prove this:
$$
\biggl(\lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} (f+g)(x, y) = K + L \biggl)
\Rightarrow
\biggl(\lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} f(x, y) = K \biggl) 
\land
\biggl( \lim_{(x, y)\to(a, b)} g(x, y) = L \biggl)
$$

Is this proposition true? If it's true, how to prove it using epsilon-delta definition? I perceive that something wrong with the proposition but I don't know what it is.

Comment: It is not true. You could have $K+L=M$ but there is an infinite amount of ways that $K+L$ can equal $M$. For instance, if $M=4$, is $(K,L)=(2,2)$ or is it $(1,3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the very extreme case, for instance, $f(x,y)=1/x$ and $g(x,y)=-1/x$, then surely $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}(f+g)(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}0=0$, but none of $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)$ or $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}g(x,y)$ exists.